# pick_event command in Canopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, canopy

I recently upgraded computers and I switch from using Python to Canopy Express since all the packages I use in my coding comes included in Canopy. However, when I went to run a program I wrote that uses matplotlib to create interactive plots that I could click on data points using 'pick_event' in Canopy, I'm getting a few issues with the program that I didn't have in Python. When I run the program, Canopy displays the graph and then immediately moves to the next line of code. This creates a problem for me since I want the graph to be interactive and it doesn't give me a chance to choose my data points I want. I have found ways to leave the graph up (adding in a raw input after displaying the plot or not closing the plot in the program) but Canopy crashes when I try to move or click on the plot. Is there any way I can fix this issue so I can use 'pick_event' command?

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's hard to find a problem in code you don't see. Read [help how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that your code is not written to optionally run in IPython's %pylab mode (or, equivalently in this context, %matplotlib mode), which starts a GUI event loop for you and in many cases makes interactions between prompt and GUI easier. You might consider adapting your code to be able to do this, but meanwhile you can test this hypothesis by disabling pylab mode in the Canopy Preference menu (Python tab).

This article may be relevant:
[Using Wx/WxPython in Canopy's IPython panel](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204470010-Using-Wx-WxPython-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel)

Comment: I believe this was the issue. I did change these settings before I posted on here but it didn't work for me. After I restarted Canopy, it seems to be working with no issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Stack Exchange protocol: Don't leave a question hanging when it has actually been answered. See [this article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to find a way to accept the answer but I guess I just missed the giant check mark next to the answer.